# How to fix "Same data being made available to all Listview items being clicked"

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

When a Listview item is clicked, data specific to that Listview item should be made available to it from SQLite database but data from all Listview items is being made available. How do I correct this?

Main2Activity:

```
position = intent.getIntExtra("position",0);

 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String text = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, ""+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

  add_data.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String place = editText.getText().toString();
            if(!place.equals("")&& databaseHelper1.insertData1(place)){
                editText.setText("");
                listItem.clear();
                viewData1();
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Data not added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}

private void viewData1() {

    Cursor cursor = databaseHelper1.viewData1(position);

    if(cursor.getCount()==0){

        Toast.makeText(this, "No data to show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else
    {
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

            listItem.add(cursor.getString(0));
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

}

DatabaseHelper:
These are my tables:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +      DB_TABLE + " (" + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME
        + " TEXT " + ")";
private static final String CREATE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE1 + " (" + ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
        PLACE + " TEXT " + " , " + ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + DB_TABLE + ")";
```

My insertData function:

```
public boolean insertData1(String place) {

    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues1 =  new ContentValues();
    contentValues1.put(PLACE,place);


    long result1 = sqLiteDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE1,null,contentValues1);
    return result1 != -1;
}
```

My viewData function:

```
public Cursor viewData1(int position)
{
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    if (position==0) {
    String query = "Select " + DB_TABLE1 + "." + PLACE + " from " + DB_TABLE1;
        cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

}
    if (position==1) {
        String query = "Select " + DB_TABLE1 + "." + PLACE + " from " + DB_TABLE1;
        cursor= sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

    }
    return cursor;
}
```

With this code, I get all the data from the database being made available to a Listitem position irrespective if it is position 0 or 1.
The actual output should be that each data is consistent with the item clicked.

Comment: Can you show us the exact SQL you're using in `viewData1`? To me it seems that the SQL is identical for both `position==0` and `position==1` ?

Comment: send full adapter code

Comment: I am passing the 'position' from the Main2Activity ( its present in the viewData1 function above) which is basically the position clicked. Wont I be using the same SQL because it depends on the position clicked but the same table . @Corion

Comment: I added the code @Radesh

Comment: Looking at the `viewData1` function, it runs the _same_ SQL, no matter whether `position` is 1 or 0. Please show me where the SQL is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an Item from within a ListView you set the ListView's **onItemClickListener** and the **onItemClick** method is invoked.

**onItemClick** is passed 4 parameters:-

1. The AdapterView of the Item that was clicked,
2. the View withing the AdapterView that was clicked,
3. the position within the list of the clicked item as an offset (i.e. 0 being the first item, 1 being the second and so on) and
4. if the Adapter is a Cursor Adapter the id  of the row that was clicked ()it it is not a Cursor adpater then this value will be the same as position, except that it is a long rather than an int.

As you are not using a CursorAdapter but a List/ArrayListAdapter then position can be used, via the Adapter's getItemAtPositition method to retrieve the string of the selected item. You could, if that String is unique use this to retrieve the row associated with that item. If it is not unique then there is no real way to ascertain exactly which row is associated with the item.

This is one of the issues with just using/extracting the string to be displayed, it's not ideal and additionally it requires extra work.

You could whilst extracting the string from the Cursor also extract the **id** and place it into an array of longs and then access this array of longs according to the position. With the **id** you can then query the table to get that row from the database.

You could have a class that defines an object that represents a row, including the **id** of the row ans then have an ArrayList in which case the getItemAtPosition method could return the object including the **id** (and perhaps all values negating the need to then access the database).

Perhaps the easiest way would be to utilise a Cursor Adapter in which case the Cursor would be available (and positioned appropriately) and the 4th parameter would be the **id** of the selected item. However, this requires that a specififc column name is used for the **id** column, that is the column must be named **_id**. This could be achieved by renaming the **ID1** column or alternately giving the **ID1** and alias using the **AS** keyword.

### Working Example

Your code appears to have a few issues and quite a few omissions. As such here's a working example based upon your code.

This example will display the ListView with 5 rows, each row being made up of the data from both tables as per the relationship. Clicking an Item will Toast the underlying values.

DatabaseHelper.java :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_TABLE = "dbtable";
    public static final String DB_TABLE1 = "dbtable1";
    public static final String COL_TABLE_ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_TABLE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_TABLE1_ID1 = BaseColumns._ID;
    public static final String COL_TABLE1_ID1_ALTERNATIVE = DB_TABLE1 + "_" + COL_TABLE1_ID1; //alternative column name so no ambiguity
    public static final String COl_TABLE1_PLACE = "place";
    public static final String COL_TABLE1_ID = "id";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;



    //Note AUTOINCREMENT removed not needed/inefficient

    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +      DB_TABLE + " (" +
            COL_TABLE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL_TABLE_NAME + " TEXT " +
            ")";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE1 + " (" +
            COL_TABLE1_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + //(limits 1 to 1 relationship, due to needing to be unique)
            COl_TABLE1_PLACE + " TEXT " + " , " +
            COL_TABLE1_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + DB_TABLE + "(" +
            COL_TABLE_ID +
            ")" +
            ")";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    // Foreign kjey support need to be turned on
    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long insertTableRow(String name) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TABLE_NAME,name);
        return mDB.insert(DB_TABLE,null,cv);
    }

    public long insertTable1Row(long table_reference, String place) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COL_TABLE1_ID,table_reference);
        cv.put(COl_TABLE1_PLACE,place);
        return mDB.insert(DB_TABLE1,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllFromBothTables() {
        String table = DB_TABLE + " JOIN " + DB_TABLE1 + " ON " + DB_TABLE + "." + COL_TABLE_ID + " = " + DB_TABLE1 + "." + COL_TABLE1_ID;
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                DB_TABLE + "." + COL_TABLE_ID,
                DB_TABLE + "." + COL_TABLE_NAME,
                DB_TABLE1 + "." + COL_TABLE1_ID1 + " AS " + COL_TABLE1_ID1_ALTERNATIVE,
                DB_TABLE1 + "." + COl_TABLE1_PLACE,
                DB_TABLE1 + "." + COL_TABLE1_ID
        };
        return mDB.query(table,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

Main2Activity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper DatabaseHelper1;
    ListView listview;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSCA;
    Cursor mCsr;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        listview = this.findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        DatabaseHelper1 = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        addSomeTestData();
        handleListView();
    }

    private void addSomeTestData() {
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(DatabaseHelper1.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHelper.DB_TABLE) > 0) return;
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTableRow("Fred");
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTableRow("Mary");
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTableRow("Sue");
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTable1Row(1,"London");
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTable1Row(2,"New York");
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTable1Row(3,"Sydney");
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTable1Row(1,"Paris");
        DatabaseHelper1.insertTable1Row(1,"Toronto");
    }

    private void handleListView() {
        mCsr = DatabaseHelper1.getAllFromBothTables();
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(mCsr);
        if (mSCA == null) {
            mSCA = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,mCsr,
                    new String[]{
                            DatabaseHelper.COL_TABLE_NAME,
                            DatabaseHelper.COl_TABLE1_PLACE
                    },
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2},
                    0
            );
            listview.setAdapter(mSCA);
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            mContext,
                            "You clicked on name = " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TABLE_NAME)) +
                                    " place = " + mCsr.getString(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COl_TABLE1_PLACE)) +
                                    " id of TABLE is " + String.valueOf(l) +
                                    " id of TABLE from cursor is " + String.valueOf(mCsr.getLong(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TABLE_ID))) +
                                    " id of TABLE1 is " + String.valueOf(mCsr.getLong(mCsr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COL_TABLE1_ID1_ALTERNATIVE))),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
        }
    }
}
```

When the above is run it looks like :-

[image]